# Using Variadic Function to pass args into a vector

Tags: c++, variadic

I am trying to make a function that adds an unknown amount of objects to a vector. I am trying to accomplish it here by just passing ints, but I cannot get it to work. Does any one know how this can be done?

*Code*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Entity
{
public:
    std::vector<int> Ints;
    
    template <typename T, typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(T first, pack ... argPack)
    {
        Ints.push_back(argPack...);
        
        for(auto& i : Ints)
            std::cout << i << "\n" << std::endl;
    };
};


int main()
{
    Entity e1;
    
    e1.AddToVector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

*Error:*

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void Entity::AddToVector(T, pack ...) [with T = int; pack = {int, int, int, int}]’:
main.cpp:32:33</span>:   required from here
main.cpp:20:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::push_back(int&, int&, int&, int&)’
```

Comment: Terminology note: this is a variadic template, a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), not a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)

Comment: Unrelated: if you're not doing this for template practice, it looks like a great place to use an initializer list.

Comment: `void AddToVector(std::initializer_list<int>)` might be simpler and more appropriate. It requires just extra `{..}` at call site: `e1.AddToVector({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 and C++14, You can use something like this:

```
private:
    void Internal_AddToVector()
    {
    }

    template <typename T, typename ... pack>
    void Internal_AddToVector(T first, pack... argPack)
    {
        Ints.push_back(first);
        Internal_AddToVector(argPack...);
    }

public:
    template <typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(pack ... argPack)
    {
        Internal_AddToVector(argPack...);

        for(auto& i : Ints)
            std::cout << i << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
public:
    template <typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(pack ... argPack)
    {
        for (auto& elem : {argPack...})
            Ints.push_back(elem);

        for(auto& i : Ints)
            std::cout << i << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
```

In C++17 and later, you can use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead:

```
public:
    template <typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(pack... argPack)
    {
        (Ints.push_back(argPack), ...);

        for(auto& i : Ints)
            std::cout << i << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Going with the initializer list theme, you can also do `Ints.insert(Ints.end(), { argPack... })`

Answer (score 2):

```
Ints.push_back(argPack...);
```

If, for example, there are for parameters this becomes:

```
Ints.push_back(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

If you refer to the specifications for `push_back()` you will find out that it takes exactly one parameter, and not four. Hence the compilation error.

The fact that your template is declares thusly:

```
    template <typename T, typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(T first, pack ... argPack)
```

this strongly suggests that your assignment's intention is for the template function to `push_back()` one value at a time:

```
Ints.push_back(first);
```

And then recursively invoke itself:

```
AddToVector(argPack...);
```

That, of course, would not be very optimal, however I'm optimistic that modern C++ compilers will be able to optimize most of this away.

But there is still one more detail that must be taken care of: an empty parameter pack. This is a guaranteed eventuality and overload resolution will fail. Therefore you must provide a do-nothing overload, for that eventuality:

```
void AddToVector()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
[[maybe_unused]] int dummy[sizeof...(pack)] = {(Ints.push_back(argPack), 0)...};
```

or

```cpp
([&]{Ints.push_back(argPack);}(), ...);
```

will do the job. I'm not sure what standard these are supported onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You want to push back all the values. `push_back` only accepts one argument. If you're using C++17 or greater, use a fold expression:

```cpp
class Entity
{
public:
    std::vector<int> Ints;
    
    template <typename T, typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(T first, pack ... argPack)
    {
        (Ints.push_back(argPack), ...);
        
        for(auto& i : Ints)
            std::cout << i << "\n" << std::endl;
    };
};


int main()
{
    Entity e1;
    
    e1.AddToVector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, a for loop:

```cpp
class Entity
{
public:
    std::vector<int> Ints;
    
    template <typename T, typename ... pack>
    void AddToVector(T first, pack ... argPack)
    {
        for (auto& elem : {argPack...}) Ints.push_back(elem);
        
        for(auto& i : Ints)
            std::cout << i << "\n" << std::endl;
    };
};


int main()
{
    Entity e1;
    
    e1.AddToVector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neither of your solutions is pushing the `first` parameter into the vector.